# How to display WFS in OpenLayers 6?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-6

i trying to display vector layer as WFS from local GeoServer in OpenLayers 6.3.1. When i trying add new vector layer, at the map i see only base map. However all data at GeoServer has projection EPSG:3857.
How to fix this problem?
My code:

```
 var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  format: new GeoJSON(),
  url: function(extent) {
    return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/geodata/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=geodata%3Amlink&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson';
        
  },
  
  strategy: bboxStrategy,
});


var vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource
});




var map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(), //projection: 'EPSG:3857',
      opacity: 0.7
    }),
    vector],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new View({
    //projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    center: [6181942.5743,7443423.3883],
    zoom: 11
    //maxZoom: 19,
    //zoom: 12
  })
});
```

Comment: please use the [edit] button to add the first feature returned to OpenLayers. or any error message if there are no features.

Comment: OpenLayers may be assuming the json data is EPSG:4326, try specifying EPSG:3857  `format: new GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857'}),`

Comment: Also you shouldn't use a bbox strategy unless you use the extent in the url